# Printing pages of AngularJS app to PDF

Tags: angularjs, pdf, printing, client-side

I have an Angular JS single-page application used for reporting. I would like to print the report as rendered client-side to PDF format, taking into consideration certain elements users may have dynamically shown or hidden.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Add class to div `no-print`
and css,

```
@media print {
  .no-print{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

and print using,

```
javascript:window.print()
```